# unwanted horizontal scroll bar due to positioning

Tags: html, css

I am making a web page for my website and a horizontal scroll bar has popped up while i was working and I can't seem to get rid of it. Can someone help me with how to get rid of it? It is most likely an error with positioning or padding.

```css
  /*PLAYER PAGE*/
.container {
  padding: 40px 20px 0;
  max-width: 2000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(105, 105, 105);
  border-width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1;
  color: white;
}
h1 span {
  display: block;
  animation: reveal 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.5s;
}

.meet-the-owner h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 215, 0);
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
}

.luxxreno {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 400px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  bottom: 40px;
}

.luxxreno img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 600px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.meet-the-owner {
  padding: 50px;
}
.q-l {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: right;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  bottom: 130px;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.questions p {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}
.luxx-name {
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.owner {
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  color: red;
}
.luxx-socials {
  position: relative;
  left: 9px;
  top: 50px;
}
.luxx-socials a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}
@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="menu-header">
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/HD_FILE (2).png" /></a>
    <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
      <i class="fas fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="news.html">News</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="players.html">Players</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="partners.html">Partners</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="about-us.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
  </nav>
</div>

<!--END OF NAV-->

<section class="player-bios">

  <div class="container">
    <h1>
        <span>Players</span>
    </h1>
</div>

<div class="meet-the-owner">

<h3>Meet the Owner</h3>
<img src="images/luxx.jpg">
<div class="q-l">
<div class="questions">
  <h2 class="luxx-name">LUXXRENO</h2>
  <h2 class="owner">OWNER</h2>
  <p>Real Name: <b>Cory George</b></p>
  <p>Online Name: <b>Luxx Reno</b></p>
  <p>First Game Played as a Kid: <b>Duck Hunter/Super Nintendo</b></p>
  <p>Game I'm Best At: <b>Fortnite</b></p>
  <p>If You Were a Superhero, What Would Your Power Be?: <b>Mimicry, so I'd be able to mimic and super power I see.</b></p>
  <p>Hidden Talents: <b>Won lots of medals for swimming!</b></p>
</div>
<a href="#">487 @ YouTube</a><br>
<a href="#">2.6k @ Instagram</a><br>
<a href="#">3k @ Twitch</a><br>
<a href="#">2.5k @ Twitter</a><br>
<a href="#">657k @ TikTok</a><br>
</section>


<!--FOOTER-->

<footer>
  <div class="footer-headers">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="news.html">News</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="players.html">Players</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="partners.html">Partners</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="about-us.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="foot-logo">
    <img src="images/HD_FILE (2).png" />
    
  </div>
  <div class="socials">

    <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@luxxmob?lang=en"> <i class="fab fa-tiktok"></i></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/LuxxMob"> <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/TheLuxxMob/"> <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="copyright">
    <h4>&copy 2021 LuxxMob</h4>
    <h4>Made with  &#10084 by <a href="https://www.instagram.com/truechow/">@truechow</a></h4>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: If you want to find the element that is overflowing you can temporarily add `*{border: 1px solid red;}` to your CSS. It will add a border to every element

Comment: good idea thank ou

Comment: i think it is the luxxreno that is causing the problem do you know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You have a border bottom on your container. Remove it.

```
border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(105, 105, 105);
```

Comment: i have removed it but it hasnt chaged

Comment: My apoligies, i thought you meant the horizontal line. The horizontal scrollbar is only showing if your content is wider than your display. You should look into adapting Flexbox
https://torquemag.io/2020/02/flexbox-tutorial/